# Change password Middleware not call

Tags: php, laravel

Hello in my project I am using the auto generated password from the admin side.And when the user try to login I am checking that user changed the password or not if password is not changes I want to redirect the user at the changepassword screen. I set changepasword middleware for it but middleware do not call the changepassword redirection Link.

changepasword middleware

```
use Closure;
use Auth;

class ChangePassword
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAutoPasswordChanged() )
        {
            return redirect('/change_password');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/tests');
        }
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'changepassword'], function () {
       Route::resource('/tests', 'TestController'); 
       Route::resource('/clients', 'ClientController'); 
});
```

Comment: Debug handle() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to app\Http\Kernel.php

and add this to `$routeMiddleware`

```
'change_password' => \App\Http\Middleware\ChangePassword::class,
```

Then in your routes, replace the middle ware line with

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'changepassword']], function () {
```

And I also believe the logic written in `ChangePassword` is wrong...

It should be

```
  if (!auth()->user()->isAutoPasswordChanged()) {
    return redirect(route('auth.change.password.get'));
  }

  return $next($request);
```

First, please use the `route()` function instead of simple string... You will not have to change the url here, if you ever change the route from your `web.php`

Since you are already using the `auth` middleware, there is no need for you to do `auth()->check()`.

Secondly, there should be a **NOT** in the condition. Because if the AutoPassword is **NOT** changed, only then redirect to the route, otherwise the use should be returned the next request and NOT redirected to **/tests**

Answer (score 0):

1. Check registration of middleware `app/Http/Kernel.php` [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware)
2. If you have a route middleware, compare the name provided in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

but my guess is:

3. `'middleware' => 'auth', 'changepassword'` should maybe changed in `'middleware' => ['auth', 'changepassword']`
4. Debug if middleware itself is called